# Another WHERE clause if there is no result

Tags: mysql

What is the best way to do this in one query in mysql?

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE language = 1
```

if there is no result

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE language = 2 AND country = 1
```

if there is no result

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE language = 2 AND country = 2
```

Comment: What columns are `*`?

Comment: This is not one query in MySQL unfortunately: what do you expect to get out of it

Comment: I think you can get the desired "logical" result with ORDER

Comment: Clarification for this question, as there have been a few answers suggesting grouping the WHERE clauses with OR:
This isn't what the OP wants, they want to have ONLY results from `language = 1`, OR ONLY the results from `language = 2 AND country = 1` OR ONLY the results from `language = 2 AND country = 2`.

Comment: Without seeing DDLs, a data set, and a desired result set, it's pretty hard to answer more definitiely, so I'll just say see COALESCE and CASE... WHEN... THEN... statements.

Comment: you seem to have use stored procedure to either fill temporary table or pass "rowset" object to client. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493932/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629324/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've edited it to make it work, but it is no longer elegant.

---

The original (without the last and not exists) had a flaw.

Turns out this isn't as clever as I thought.  See comments below.   It fails if the first and third queries return data.   It does work if you have only one union, but not two or more.

---

It's quite easy in mysql:

```
select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * from products where language = 1
union
SELECT * FROM products WHERE language = 2 AND country = 1 and found_rows()=0
union
SELECT * FROM products WHERE language = 2 AND country = 2 and found_rows()=0 
AND not exists(select * from products where language = 1)
```

See the discussion of found_rows() and SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows

Comment: Can you rely on found_rows in a UNION statement?

Comment: @gbn You can if you're not using LIMIT anywhere and checking for 0.

Comment: Umm..I think it's salvageable actually.. What about enclosing the other 2 statements in a select so, then it is actually:
1 statement-Union-1 statement holding 2 nested statements.

Comment: @meewoK nesting them didn't work and you can't put another SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like the following: (edited to use EXISTS and LIMIT based on comments).

```
(
SELECT * FROM products WHERE language = 1
)
UNION
(
SELECT * FROM products WHERE language = 2 AND country = 1
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT count(*) FROM products WHERE language = 1 limit 1)
)
UNION
(
SELECT * FROM products WHERE language = 2 AND country = 2 
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT count(*) FROM products WHERE language = 2 AND country = 1 limit 1)
AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT count(*) FROM products WHERE language = 1 limit 1)
)
```

You check with nested queries and count(*) that previous queries were NULL.

Comment: Using not exists might be better than checking for a 0 count.

Comment: @ShawnBalestracci will those subqueries (COUNT or EXISTS - doesn't matter) be re-executed on every row ? Maybe left join + check for null would be better approach ?

Comment: I have a strong feeling the optimizer calculates the optimum branch and pre-calculates those only once. That is why SQL engines do :).

Comment: @Shawn Balestracci Thanks, I will check into not exists and update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL lacks features to allows this in one go
Examples: `DENSE_RANK` window function, or [`TOP..WITH TIES`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9392470/27535)

So, without using a temporary table or IF statements (which require a stored procedure in MySQL anyway), then filter this on the client to the lowest priority value. That is, consume rows until the value changes

```
SELECT *, 1 AS priority FROM products WHERE language = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 2 AS priority FROM products WHERE language = 2 AND country = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT *, 3 AS priority FROM products WHERE language = 2 AND country = 2
ORDER BY priority;
```

This does remove roundtrips to the MySQL server, even if not ideal. And it also avoids re-evaluating the previous SELECTs in EXISTS clauses

Comment: You could do this in a single select if you evaluated priority as a case condition - something like `case language when 1 then 1 when 2 then language + country else 4 end`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select p.* 
from (select min(language) minlang, min(country) minctry 
      from products where language = 1 or
                          (language = 2 and country in (1,2)) ) c
join products p 
on p.language = c.minlang and (c.minlang=1 or p.country=c.minctry)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no good way and if possible, you'd better make it into a procedure, either filling the temporary table or returning RowSet object to client

- [SELECT-ing data from stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493932)
- [MySql stored procedures: How to select from procedure table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629324/)

However if nothing that is possible you seem to have limit the secondary and tertiary queries:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE language = 1

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM products WHERE language = 2 AND country = 1 
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM products WHERE language = 1)

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM products WHERE language = 2 AND country = 2
   AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM products WHERE language = 1 OR (language = 2 AND country = 1 ))
```

But that just must be ugly and slow.

Maybe LEFT JOIN with IS NULL would be better than NOT EXISTS though